# Como posso responder uma pergunta realizada do cmd?

Tags: cmd, bat

Estou automatizando um processo através de um arquivo .bat e em um determinado momento o cmd me realiza uma pergunta, gostaria de saber como posso fazer pra responder.

Tentei:

```
    jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk alias_name //Meu comando que solicita uma senha no cmd

    "/senhaultrasecreta" //resposta que devo dar ao cmd

pause
```

Também tentei apenas "senhaultrasecreta" mas o cmd tenta executar como um arquivo.

Há alguma forma de responder essa mensagem automaticamente?

@Edit:

Tentei o `echo "senhaultrasecreta"`
mas ele não é escrito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem se interessar, consegui responder usando "|" e ao lado esquerdo a mensagem que quero que seja digitada:

```
echo senhaultrasecreta | jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Não entendi porque tantos downvotes e nenhuma resposta/feedback pra minha pergunta